# Some websites on IIS are down, no possibility to start them. Others are running fine

Tags: web, iis-8

All of a suddon some sites are stopped in my IIS (Windows 2019), unclear why, and in the details only "Configuration editor" and "IIS Permissions" are available. I don't have the "Manage website" options in the Actions pane for those sites. So I don't know how to start these sites.

Some other sites are running fine.
All Application pools are running.
I already restarted IIS and even the complete server (Windows 2019).
Why don't I have all settings of those sites available?
What is happening?

[image: Sites are stopped and I don't have the "Manage website" options in the action pane to be able to start them.]

Comment: When you took the screen shot, did you open IIS Manager directly on the server or remotely?

Comment: Directly on the server, logged on as administrator, as always

Comment: Looks like TCP is not listening on port 80
netstat -abn | find ":80"
--> nothing

Comment: I encountered the same issue before. You just need to remove the site and add it again.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but it is not just 1site. I have 37 sites in this case. Only 10 are ok.
Removing them and adding again 1by1 is hard. I see that those 37 sites lost their bindings in ApplicationHost.config file.
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8098:" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:mysite" />
</bindings>
When I add this I can start one site. For another I get : “This website cannot be started. Another website may be using the same port”.  Which is strange because that is exactly what I had before when it was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a backup of a few days ago and did restore of the Applicationhost.config file under
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config
Then I restarted IIS and now all sites are again running (and manageable).
Unclear why the applicationhost.config got "corrupted" but my problem is solved.

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.